# Implementing List#flatMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there a better functional way to write `flatMap`?

```
def flatMap[A,B](list: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] =
    list.map(x => f(x)).flatten
```

Conceptually, I understand `flatMap` in terms of `flatten`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternate approach:

```
def flatMap[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] =
  list.foldLeft(List[B]())(_ ++ f(_))
```

I don't know about “better”. (And if we start talking about efficient implementation, that's another can of worms...)

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about the `fold` approach.

Comment: That works on a `flatMap` for `List`. It would work for a state monad, for example.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, since you're mentioning examples where it would work, are there monads for which my implementation would **not** work?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I meant it would _not_ work for a state monad... :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to flesh out the answers, you could also define this as a recursive function using pattern matching:

```
def flatMap[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = list match {
  case (x::xs) => f(x) ++ flatMap(xs)(f)
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Or make it explicitly tail-recursive:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def flatMapTailRec[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = {
  @tailrec
  def _flatMap(result: List[B])(input: List[A])(f: A => List[B]): List[B] = input match {
    case (x::xs) => _flatMap(f(x) ++ result)(xs)(f)
    case _ => result
  }
  _flatMap(List[B]())(list)(f)
}
```

I did a bit of quick, non-rigorous benchmarking, using sample input of:

```
val input = (0 to 1000).map(_ => (0 to 1000).toList).toList
```

In order from fastest to slowest:

- `flatMap(input)(x => x)`

  - **0.02069937453** seconds
- `flatMapTailRec(input)(x => x)`

  - **0.02335651054** seconds
- `input.flatMap(x => x)`

  - **0.0297564358** seconds
- `flatMapFoldLeft(input)(x => x)`

  - **12.940458234** seconds

I'm a little surprised that `foldLeft` comes out so much slower than the others. It would be interested to see how `flatMap` is actually defined in the source. I tried looking myself, but there's too much to go through at the moment >_>.

**Edit**: As Daniel Sobral pointed out in the comments of another answer, these implementations are restricted to `List[A]`. You could write a more generic implementation that would work for any mappable type. The code would quickly become much more complicated.

Comment: Regarding `foldLeft`'s slowness, see my answer. Also, you would have a hard time writing a generic `flatMap` in terms of `map`. That's the binding (`++` or `flatten` for lists) that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is already pretty functional, and emphasize where `flatMap` name comes from. Note that `x => f(x)` is `f`, so it boils down to:

```
list.map(f).flatten
```

Using `foldLeft` is a terrible idea, due to quadratic behavior induced in concatenation. E.g. `(((a++b)++c)++d)++List()` would iterate 4 times on `a`, 3 times on `b`, etc.

Fine would be `foldRight`.