# Implement FreeMonad#flatMap & map

Tags: scala

Going through the "External Effects and I/O" chapter of [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I'm working on this exercise:

> // Exercise 1: Free is a monad for any choice of F. Implement map
>   // and flatMap methods on the Free trait, and give the Monad instance 
>   for Free[F,_]

Here's the base code (source - the book)

```
 sealed trait Free[F[_], A]
  case class Return[F[_], A](a: A) extends Free[F, A]
  case class Suspend[F[_], A](s: F[Free[F,A]]) extends Free[F,A]
  case class FlatMap[F[_],A,B](s: Free[F,A],
                                f: A => Free[F, B]) extends Free[F,B]

  def freeMonad[F[_]]: Monad[({type f[a] = Free[F, a]})#f] = {
    new Monad[({type f[x] = Free[F[_], x]})#f] {
      override flatMap
    }

  }
```

From previous exercises, I know how to implement `flatMap` on a "concrete" [ListMonad#flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20436614/409976). So as not to give me the full answer, could you please direct/show me how to implement one of these functions on the Free monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's remove the duplication:

```
type Free1[F[_]] = ({type f[a] = Free[F, a]})#f
```

Write down the complete type:

```
override def flatMap[A, B](mx: Free1[A])(mf: A => Free1[B]): Free1[B] = ...
```

Rewrite it in terms of `Free` by putting in the definition of `Free1`:

```
override def flatMap[A, B](mx: Free[???, ???])(mf: ???): ??? = ...
```

The only thing we can obviously do is pattern match on `mx`:

```
override def flatMap[A, B](mx: Free[???, ???])(mf: ???): ??? = mx match {
  case Return(a) => ... // what can we do with a and mf to get the correct type?
  case ...
}
```

If you put in the correct types in the definition above, the right-hand side should be relatively easy to fill in (and if you don't, the compiler will most likely say `flatMap overrides nothing`). I could expand the answer if desired, but prefer to err on the "not giving the full answer" side :)

Answers to the questions:

> not sure how to extract Free[F,A] from Suspend(s: F[Free[F, A]])

You can't, since you know nothing about `F`. Is there a way to do without it?

> calling flatMap(Return(a))(mf) seems to fit the signature of flatMap

Does it? We have `a: Free[F, A]` and so `Return(a): Free[F, Free[F, A]]`, so `flatMap(Return(a))` takes a `Free[F, A] => Free[F, B]` and `mf: A => Free[F, B]` doesn't fit. You also should include `f` in the result (as well as `a` and `mf`).

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as you can go without giving it away.

Comment: `type Free1[F[_]] = ({type f[a] = Free[F, a]})#f` is a type lambda, which says "Free1, the type, accepts a higher kinded type (Option[X], List[X], etc.) and returns a new `Free[F, a]`?

Comment: To be a bit more precise, it accepts `Option[X]` (etc.) and returns a higher-kinded type as well. _This_ type accepts a type like `Int` and returns `Free[Option, Int]`.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyRomanov. Would you please look at my gist & questions - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/9907255?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - I tried to pattern match on `F`, but the compiler couldn't find the type. Similar to: `scala> val x = List(Some(1))
x: List[Some[Int]] = List(Some(1)) |
scala> x match {
     |   case List(Some(a)) => a
     | }
res0: Int = 1`

Comment: Well, as I said, we don't know _anything_ about `F`. E.g. it could be `type Const[A] = Int`, in which case it's obviously impossible to extract `A` from it. I'll add that you already have an answer for `Suspend` elsewhere!